# Optional login with Shiro

Tags: java, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro in my java application to provide authentication and permission to my application.

I have my rest-api bind to authcBasic[permissive], rest.

And my webapplication  bind to /** = authc

By default, authc will requires the requesting user to be authenticated to be able to access to the content. But in my application, I want to be able to let the unknown user to access the app without login and display only certain type of content and let the user the choice of login or not.

Is there any way to achieve that with Shiro? I was thinking about removing the authc and create a custom login function via my rest api. But i am not sure if it will be enough.

Thanksss.

Comment: This was asked a while ago - did you ever figure it out?